# How to include ol.Attributions in openlayers 3 custom build

Tags: openlayers, attribution

I am updating my custom build of OpenLayers 3 after adding some new features to my app.  Everything works fine when I call `http://openlayers.org/en/v3.19.1/build/ol.js` but when I attempt to create my custom build and run the app, I receive the error `Error: ol.Attribution is not a constructor` in the browser.

I have tried `ol.Attribution`, `ol.Attribution.*`, `ol.Attribution#*`, `ol.Attribution`, and `ol.control.Attribution` in the exports array of my `ol-custom.json` file.  Nothing seems to be working.

What do I need to add to my `ol-custom.json` file to make this work ?

Comment: If your custom build with 'ol.Attribution' passes, it's not only about ol.Attribution problem. need some more relative error messages.